# Is there a way to mute a tab in Google Chrome using AppleScript?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, applescript

So I wanted to make a little script that e.g. mutes all tabs whose URL contains google.com. I wanted to do something like this:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set theWindows to windows of application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with theWindow in theWindows
        set theTabs to (tabs of theWindow whose URL contains "google.com")
        repeat with theTab in theTabs
            tell theTab
                mute
            end tell
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

But if you try to run this, you will soon notice that Applescript thinks `mute` is a variable. I also tried `mute tab` but it also doesn't work.

Comment: I doubt you can do this casually but (assuming that chrome functions similarly to vivaldi) you could probably use UI scripting to right-click a tab and mute it. Through more standard means, you could likely use applescript to determine which tabs to feed to this procedure.

Comment: @Mockman I want to get away from UI scripting since it's brute-force-y and getting the right tab to right click is probably hard and then clicking it using third party shell utilities is even harder. I just wanted to ask if there was a better method of doing this.

Comment: I feel the same way about UI scripting. I find it exhausting to work with. But unless chrome offers scriptable media playback control in their tabs, which I doubt, you don't have many options. Vivaldi can be set to mute all background tabs, or prioritize the active tab. If chrome has similar settings, that's probably as close as you'll get.

Comment: @Mockman I found a solution: In Chrome, there is a Menu Bar item called `Tab` which has an item called `Mute site`. I know that there is a way to select options from the Menu Bar but the code I wrote (`tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of front window to select (first item of menu "Tab" whose title is equal to "Mute site"`) does not work since apparently menu items don't understand select. If you know how to do it, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Inside a system events tell block: `tell process "Google Chrome" to menu item "Mute site" of menu "Tab" of menu bar 1`. This page has details on getting menu items, etc…. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html

Comment: @Mockman Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should allow for the muting of tabs:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click ¬
        menu item "Mute Site" of ¬
        menu 1 of ¬
        menu bar item "Tab" of ¬
        menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Chrome"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no default keyboard shortcut assigned for the **Tab Menu Item “Mute Site” in Google Chrome**. However, you can assign it a custom keyboard shortcut and use it manually or in an **AppleScript** with a `keystroke` or `key code` command.

This following image shows how I assigned that custom keyboard shortcut.

[image]

Once your custom keyboard shortcut is properly set up, this following AppleScript code is an example of how I personally have mine set up.

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate

delay 0.1

tell application "System Events"
    key code 49 using {shift down, command down}
end tell
```

Comment: What's with the **Tab->** as **Mute Site** is all that should be necessary.

Comment: “In the Menu Title field, type the menu command for which you want to create a shortcut, exactly as the command appears in the app, including the > character (type ->), ellipses (type three periods without spaces or press Option-; (semi-colon)), or other punctuation. 

For example, to set a shortcut for the default ligature command in TextEdit (Format > Font > Ligatures > Use Default), you would type Format->Font->Ligatures->Use Default in the Menu Title field. To set a shortcut for the Export as PDF command (File > Export as PDF…), you would type File->Export as PDF… in the field.”

Comment: **Mute Site**, by itself, works just fine for me!

Comment: I still think that Mockman‘s solution is a bit better since it has no UI scripting and it works for everybody if english is the language of their system and they don‘t need to assign any custom keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Mute site, worked (->site written in lower case)